# How to get the passed and failed test cases count from Extent Report html

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

How to get the passed and failed test cases count from Extent Report html and display the counts in the Console after Selenium test execution

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your TestLister you can set on methods:

1. onTestFailure
2. onTestSuccess

the next variables:

1. int failTC = 0;
2. int passTC = 0

and then in the methods add +1 and onFinish print the results.